# Terminal crashing while building from source code

Tags: ubuntu, build, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm currently trying to build [ANTs](http://stnava.github.io/ANTs/) from the source code, and encountering a strange problem: `make -j 4`, which is recommended when building ANTs by the developer, seems to freeze after a while, which is followed by the terminal window it's running in closing without throwing any sort of identifiable error. Is there any way to resolve this?

Information:
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 inside of a VMware virtual machine, with 6GB of RAM and 160 GB of storage allocated. The VM has previously experienced assorted instabilities.

I made sure that make is up to date using apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when trying to build g2opy using `make -j8` in Ubuntu Oracle virtual machine with 5 GB RAM and 50 GB storage. The terminal and the browser would shut down without any messages when building.
I solved the issue by increasing swap size to 10 GB, following this link:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04/

And I increased the memory to 10 GB RAM, then I was able to build the package. I think this is a memory issues (at least for me). I hope this would help solve your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue building source code. It is probably a memory problem, but first you should check your system log to see what the issue is:

> tail -f /var/log/syslog

Mine was related to a Ubuntu daemon "systemd-oomd" which limits the RAM of a terminal application to no more than 50% by default. You can disable that using:

> sudo systemctl disable --now systemd-oomd

And you can enable it back later. See this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404888/how-do-i-disable-the-systemd-oom-process-killer-in-ubuntu-22-04